# Fusion Tables vs. Postgres with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to draw 5 sets ~30k markers to a Google map at a time, which set is drawn depends on user input/selection.

I've noticed very slow load times by the application in rendering the points using the following code.

```
function set_markers(minyear,maxyear,minprice,maxprice){

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 // this method is used to capture the response of the http request
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     var pinpoints = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
     var marker;
     var i=0;
     var lat;
     var lng;
     var price;
     var address;
     var post_latlng;
     var content;
     for (i = 0;i<pinpoints.length;i++){ 
        a=pinpoints[i];
        lat=parseFloat(a["lat"]);
        lng=parseFloat(a["lng"]);
        price=parseFloat(a["price"]);
        address=String(a["address_string"]);
        date=String(a["date_of_sale"]);
        post_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        content ="<b>Address:</b> " + address + "</br>" + "<b>Price:</b>€ " + price + '</br>' + "<b>Date of Sale:</b> " + date;  
        add_marker(address,post_latlng);
        add_InfoWindow(content,marker);
      }
     }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/pinpoints.php?lat1="+lat1+"&lat2="+lat2+"&lng1="+lng1+"&lng2="+lng2+"&minyear="+minyear+"&maxyear="+maxyear+"&minprice="+minprice+"&maxprice="+maxprice,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function add_marker(add,posit){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
        map: map, 
        title: add,
        position: posit  
      });
}
function add_InfoWindow(con,mark){
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(mark,con,infowindow{ 
    return function(){
     infowindow.setContent(con);
     infowindow.open(map,mark);
    };
  })(marker,content,infowindow)); 
 }
```

I am wondering if using Fusion Tables would speed up this process and still allow me to draw the points as specified in the Javascript code above? If so, how can I call a Fusion Table from my Javascript and store the return in a JSON array so as I can cause minimal disruption to the application when switching from PHP/Postgres to Fusion Tables. I've already created the relevant Fusion Table, I just need to know if and how to connect it?

Suggestions on how to optimise the above code to speed up running time are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what the application is supposed to do, but best guess is that you'd want to use a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) with the Google Maps JavaScript API and alter the query based on user input.

Comment: Basicially the application is supposed to add markers to a map based on if the fit certain criteria specified through user input such as price-range. I have this feeding through fine, I am just wondering if there is a way to render these points faster and how I can implement it.

Comment: I think you will find FT considerably faster to render than moving 30k points to the client. Take a look at Derek Eder's Searchable Map Template for filterable maps built with Fusion Tables: http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/

Answer (score 0):

Your code execution is slow because you are adding each pont as a marker which means the client(your browser) is doing all the hard work now. These markers are clickable, editable, moveable..and so on by Javascript.

Fusion Tables can help you displaying tens of thousands of points by rendering them on server side(google's servers). This means you will not be using markers anymore. Your points will be rendered on the map tiles(image files) served by google. They will not be clickable anymore in the normal sense.

You can filter the displayed points on your Fusion Table based on your users input, but there are limitations to it. Eg.: if your users are selecting from a dropdown, that's achievable by providing a WHERE clause on your Fusion Tables query. If your users are selecting points by multiple dimensions using multiple dropdowns and/or checkboxes you may hit the URL size limit.

Without providing your use case its hard to tell more...

Comment: The purpose/use case is to draw markers with infowindows on a map. The markers are not meant to be movable, editable etc. by default.
Based on the user changing a draggable circle on the map, and changing 2 sliders the values of these are used to determine which points are drawn
So its likely that less than 3k points need to be drawn at a given time.

Comment: I'm guessing your users will restrict the results with the 2 sliders giving an upper and lower boundary on one of your Fusion Table fields(price..maybe) and probably the circle serves as the search radius. You need to build your [query](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer#fusion_table_queries) dynamically each time a user changes your sliders or moves the circle. You can use spatial condition in your query to limit the search radius. A good starting point is [this example](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/circle_example)

Comment: That example looks like what I'm looking for, the only issue I'm having is how to implement that with a draggable and adjustable circle

Answer (score -1):

There are a few factors to consider here when it comes to loading large items from a database onto a map/clients display.. The best answer here *IMHO* is to do something similar to below .

- Have you used the browsers inspector/dev tools or any javascript to measure how long after the ajax request is complete to when the map finishes loading the markers. Same goes for the php and sql side of things.
- Indexing.... Do these lookup columns have a index? You will be amazed at the performance difference..
- Measure the sql query time, any time taken to modify your data on php's side.
- If you already have a powerful enough database/server, you should be able to avoid fusion tables easily.. This is a self made choice, use judgement.
- Do you need interaction with the loaded items? If so then markers or similar will be the only true correct way. Layers are quicker and can be saved as a single object for later use but you can not interact with the points.
- Do you need all items at once from the start or can you load them as required. Some times using a delayed ajax call to get the markers within the visible area on the maps interaction events will perform extremely well and allows the markers to be loaded over time...cache and check a id column.
- Benchmark each part of the process.. Finding the slow points and tweaking your code around them will always lead to the best performance.. Explore alternative functions/methods/loop styles/sql queries...
- Clustering might be an alternative method if you can find a style to match your display and the information feedback is acceptable for your use case.

**You could get complex** and store a unix timestamp for each measure point and add them to the output data then add more timestamps via javascript, once everything is done, just console.log it or have a table generated below the map showing the timing per point. This can be very handy when tweaking code as it shows any major differences (ignoring network performance)

**Stages Of Rows/Array Of Data To The Map:**

1. SERVER: Querying the rows from the database into a collection or sending the rows directly to the client request.
2. SERVER: Cleanup / formatting the rows and sending them to the client request
3. CLIENT: Receiving the data into a collection or adding directly to the map.

**1: Querying the rows from the database...**
While SQL is not one of my favorite languages, its something that more and more i do try to optimize as i need quicker results as a result of "Big Data" and trying to squeeze every little cpu tick out of a server can save some big $$$ in the long run.

Depending on your final code/setup... you can increase performance with doing simple things like for a ajax request.

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table_poi;");
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo json_encode(pg_fetch_assoc($result));
exit;
```

**2: Cleanup / formatting...**
Basically you should try to make sure you do not have to loop the database results before sending them to the client or else it will be wasted time/resources.. use array mapping if you have to.. try to index your arrays so you can use key lookups in javascript.

**3: Receiving the data into a collection...**
Your javascript at a quick glance looks fine, the first thing i would benchmark/test here is how long after the ajax request is complete until all the markers are loaded.. This will depend on your computer speed, not the server you are working on... This is the part that requires finding a good balance of speed vs current age of commonly used devices/performance of devices.